# Blur alpha png with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, pixastic

I am trying to simulate depth of field in the browser. I have used Pixastic to blur images but it doesn't blur th edges of transparent pngs. Is there a solution that will blur between alpha values?

Answer (score 2):

The best alternative is to used blurred images only.

Else, you can use this script - http://www.quasimondo.com/BoxBlurForCanvas/FastBlurDemo.html